# sentiment analysis sum score in R

Tags: r, sentiment-analysis

I am trying to get a sum score from my sentiment analysis.
This is my dataset:
https://www.mediafire.com/file/uei2e3tajvi7wao/full_data.csv/file

I am expecting to see each row with the summed sentiment score. (I have 4042 rows, and each row is identified as its unique "number" starting from 1 to 4042).

This is what I want to make:

| number | Full_article | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1. text here | 4 |
| 2 | 2. text here | 2 |
| 3 | 3. text here | 10 |
| 4 | 4. text here | -5 |

However, after running my code, it only shows one row with the summed score of the whole value. Does anyone know what's causing an issue here? It looks like this:

|  | Sentiment |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | -25515 |

```
library(textdata)

afinn_dictionary <- get_sentiments("afinn")
news_tokenized <- full_data %>% unnest_tokens(word, full_article, to_lower = TRUE)
head(news_tokenized$word, 10) 

news_tokenized <- news_tokenized %>% anti_join(stop_words)
head(news_tokenized$word, 10)

word_counts_senti <- news_tokenized %>% inner_join(afinn_dictionary)
colnames(word_counts_senti)

news_senti <- word_counts_senti %>% 
  group_by(number) %>% 
  summarize(sentiment = sum(value))

news_senti
```

This is the result of dput().

```
dput(head(full_data)):

dput(head(full_data))
structure(list(number = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6), publish_date = c("10/1/21 10:16", 
"10/1/21 10:49", "10/1/21 10:49", "10/1/21 11:40", "10/1/21 12:50", 
"10/1/21 13:13"), media_name = c("Wall Street Journal", "Wall Street Journal", 
"Wall Street Journal", "Wall Street Journal", "Wall Street Journal", 
"Daily Beast"), partisan_media = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2), full_article = c(NA, 
"Merck cheered investors and healthcare experts alike on Friday with the news that its COVID-19 antiviral cut the risk of hospitalization or death by roughly half in a late-stage trial, and could become a powerful tool in reining in the pandemic.The drug company MRK, +0.47% said molnupiravir, an oral antiviral developed with partner Ridgeback Biotherapeutics, reduced the risk of hospitalization or death in at-risk adult patients with mild to moderate COVID by about 50% in an interim analysis of data from a late-stage trial. The data came from 775 patients out of 1,550 that were enrolled in the trial. Merck shares soared 8% Friday as investors welcomed what would be a much-needed and long-awaited treatment for COVID. While several effective vaccines have been developed against the illness, far fewer treatments have emerged, and those that have require infusions and must be administered in a clinical setting.Molnupiravir is a pill administered orally in capsule form every 12 hours for five days, according to clinicaltrials.gov.Don’t miss: Why a pill you take at home could change the direction of the pandemicThrough Day 29 in the Phase 3 trial, no patients given molnupiravir died, compared with the eight patients who died on the placebo. The company is now planning to submit an application for emergency-use authorization for the treatment from the Food and Drug Administration and to seek authorizations from other regulatory bodies around the world.Merck plans to produce 10 million courses of treatment by year-end. The U.S. government has already committed to purchasing about 1.7 million courses of the drug, once it receives an EUA.See also: Here’s why COVID-19 booster shots are good for businessThe company said it halted the study early at the recommendation of an independent data-monitoring committee and in consultation with the FDA, because the results were so positive. Health experts applauded the news and said it would make a big difference in the fight against the coronavirus-borne illness, which has caused the deaths of almost 5 million people since the start of the outbreak. The U.S. death toll passed 700,000 on Saturday, according to data aggregated by Johns Hopkins University.The news comes as the U.S. is averaging just under 2,000 COVID deaths a day, according to a New York Times tracker, a small improvement on the recent trend. Hospitalizations and new cases have been coming down, but the daily death rate had remained at more than 2,000 for the past few weeks. Experts lament those numbers as almost all of them are in unvaccinated people, who are dying preventable deaths. The vaccines have proved highly effective at preventing serious illness and death.Alaska remains the state with the most new cases measured on a per capita basis, and its hospital system is still severely stressed. Elsewhere, some states that were recent hot spots are seeing improving trends, including Florida, which is now reporting fewer than 6,000 cases a day, down from an average of more than 20,000 cases a day during most of August.Florida has lost 55,009 of its residents to the virus and has had a total of 3.57 million confirmed cases. The state’s population, per the 2020 census, is slightly above 21.5 million.See also: The biggest risk facing investors this earnings season is lurking just beneath the surfaceThe Centers for Disease Control and Prevention’s vaccine tracker is showing that 184.9 million people living in America are fully vaccinated, equal to about 55.8% of the population, a number that has remained relatively static for weeks. Hospital staff, universally hailed as heroes in 2020 with nightly ovations raining down from windows and balconies, are now coming under threat from hostility, threats and violence from patients, who have become increasingly angry over safety rules aimed at stopping the spread of the virus, the Associated Press reported. “A year ago, we’re healthcare heroes and everybody’s clapping for us,” said Dr. Stu Coffman, a Dallas-based emergency-room physician. “And now we’re being in some areas harassed and disbelieved and ridiculed for what we’re trying to do, which is just depressing and frustrating.”Cox Medical Center Branson in Missouri started giving panic buttons to up to 400 nurses and other employees after assaults per year tripled between 2019 and 2020 to 123, a spokeswoman said. One nurse had to get her shoulder X-rayed after an attack, the AP reported. Coronavirus Update: BioNTech co-founder says COVID-19 will become manageable but may persist for several yearsElsewhere, Russia had a fourth straight record daily death toll at 887, the Moscow Times reported. That brings Russia’s official coronavirus death toll to 208,142 — Europe’s highest.Australia is planning to drop some international travel restrictions in November, BBC News reported. Australia’s decision to fully close its borders caused controversy as it left many of its citizens overseas, but it has also succeeded in controlling the spread. Australia has recorded fewer than 1,000 deaths in the pandemic.Finland will start vaccinating minks on fur farms against COVID with an experimental vaccine, NDTV.com reported. Minks have been found to be susceptible to contracting the illness and to pass it on to humans. Last year, Denmark culled its entire mink population as a cautionary measure. The World Health Organization said just 2% of the populations of half of the countries in Africa have been vaccinated against COVID, AFP reported. Fifteen of the continent’s 54 nations have managed to vaccinate at least 10% of their people, achieving a global goal for Sept. 30 set in May by the WHO. See also: 3 prominent doctors on how best to use rapid, at-home COVID tests — and which single test has ‘been shown to be very accurate’The global tally for the coronavirus-borne illness climbed above 234.3 million on Saturday, while the death toll rose above 4.79 million, according to data aggregated by Johns Hopkins University. The U.S. continues to lead the world with a total of 43.6 million cases and 700,327 deaths.India is second by cases after the U.S. at 33.8 million and has suffered 448,573 deaths. Brazil has the second highest death toll at 597,255 and 21.4 million cases. In Europe, Russia has reported the most fatalities at 205,297, followed by the U.K. at 137,171.China, where the virus was first discovered late in 2019, has had 108,500 confirmed cases and 4,809 deaths, according to its official numbers, which are widely held to be massively underreported.", 
NA, NA, "Merck and Ridgeback Biotherapeutics’ promising oral antiviral could shift the direction of the pandemic by making it easier for people with COVID-19 to take a pill at home that can keep them from getting severely sick. Merck’s MRK, +0.47% stock gained 9.1% in trading on Friday after announcing that the drug, molnupiravir, cut the risk of hospitalization or death by 50% in a Phase 3 clinical trial. (Ridgeback is privately held.)The drug, which inhibits replication of the virus, was tested in 775 “at-risk” adults with mild or moderate cases of COVID-19. No one taking the drug died in the trial; eight deaths were reported among those taking the placebo. It also appeared to work against the gamma, delta, and mu variants in the roughly 40% of participants for whom sequencing was available. “It’s a very big deal,” Dr. Eric Topol, director of the Scripps Research Translational Institute, said in an email. “If safe and inexpensive (even freely available) as a pill that is easily taken, it could have enormous benefit for reducing severe illness, for both unvaccinated and breakthrough vaccinated people.”Topol on Twitter has already referred to molnupiravir as the “M-pack,” a play on the commonly prescribed Z-Pack antibiotics.The U.S. has already ordered 1.7 million treatment courses of molnupiravir at a price of about $705 for each five-day course of treatment. That said, there are still a few caveats. The companies have so far only shared clinical data in a news release and not in a preprint or medical study. It’s also unclear if any of the participants in the trial were vaccinated and if so, how many. (Topol noted that knowing this won’t “detract from its potential importance.”)The case for new COVID-19 treatmentsThe COVID-19 vaccines are by far the best therapeutic tool in our pandemic arsenal. Not only are they very effective at preventing people from ending up in the hospital or dying, they for the most part keep people from getting even mild cases of COVID-19, though these breakthrough infections are on the rise.There are a handful of therapies that can help COVID-19 patients who are at high risk of developing severe cases or are already in the hospital, but all of them are administered by infusion in a healthcare setting. These include the monoclonal antibodies developed by Eli Lilly & Co. LLY, +0.10%, Regeneron Pharmaceuticals Inc. REGN, -0.52%, and Vir Biotechnology Inc. VIR, +1.16% and GlaxoSmithKline GSK, -1.41%. Other therapies, like Gilead Sciences Inc.’s GILD, -0.01% Veklury and the steroid dexamethasone, which has been repurposed as a COVID-19 drug, are reserved for critically ill hospitalized patients.When it comes to treatments for mild to moderate cases of COVID-19 among the general public, we have been out of luck. There are no Tamiflu-like pills that patients can take at home. “The availability of an effective oral drug that can be given in the outpatient setting can blunt the risks associated with breakthrough infections and reduce mortality in the unvaccinated, which can begin to move the nation out of the pandemic and hasten reopening,” RBC Capital Markets analyst Brian Abrahams told investors on Friday. If and when authorization or approval of molnupiravir and other investigational antivirals takes place, it will likely shift the course of the pandemic and bring us one step closer to making the virus something we can live with and less of something to be feared.“The fact that this is moving from a pandemic probably to being more endemic, there’s a real need for an antiviral,” Merck CEO Robert Davis said Sept. 13 at the Morgan Stanley Global Healthcare Conference, according to a FactSet transcript of the presentation.Other COVID-19 antivirals in developmentThere are half a dozen oral antiviral drugs in development right now, spurred by a $3 billion investment from the National Institutes of Health into COVID-19 antiviral development back in June. Pfizer Inc. PFE, -1.17%, already a pandemic favorite for its role developing Comirnaty, the first authorized and approved COVID-19 vaccine in the U.S., is expected to have late-stage clinical data for its investigational antiviral pill before the end of the year.“We think an oral is a critical piece of the solution to the pandemic,” Pfizer Chief Financial Officer Frank D’Amelio said Sept. 14 at a Morgan Stanley conference. “It could be prescribed for a 5-day treatment course at the first sign of infection before patients are hospitalized for critical care.”Both Pfizer and Merck are also testing their antivirals for post-exposure prophylaxis to COVID-19. In these instances, if someone is exposed to another person who has tested positive for the virus, they can take medication preventively to ward off a COVID-19 infection. Several other small drug makers and biotechs are also testing antivirals as COVID-19 treatments, including Adamis Pharmaceuticals Corp. ADMP, +0.61%, Atea Pharmaceuticals Inc. AVIR, -2.22%, and RedHill Biopharma Ltd. RDHL, -2.91%. Gilead has also been studying Veklury as a treatment for high-risk COVID-19 patients who have not been hospitalized. Merck said Friday it plans to soon submit the data for emergency authorization. Merck’s stock is down 3.7% for the year, while the broader S&P 500 SPX, +0.61% is up 14.7%.", 
"Joe Rogan’s streak of terrible COVID-19 takes continued this week when he baselessly suggested the White House faked President Joe Biden’s booster shot on live TV out of fear that he could have dropped dead in the moment.After Biden took questions from reporters while he received his third dose of the Pfizer jab earlier this week, Rogan used his massively popular Spotify podcast to wonder aloud if it was a “real booster.”When his guest, former CIA officer Mike Baker agreed, suggesting that it was merely “performance art,” Rogan dug deeper into his latest conspiracy theory.“I don’t think they would take the chance,” the host said. “I think if they were going to give him a booster shot, the last thing they would do is give it to him live on television. What if he dies? What if he blacks out? What if he gets it and faints? Because people have had very bad reactions, like in the moment, for whatever reason.”Earlier this year, the CDC reported 21 cases of anaphylaxis out of 1,893,360 first doses of the Pfizer-BioNTech COVID-19 vaccine.“Unless Kamala Harris talked him into it,” Rogan later joked—the implication being that she was trying to kill him so she could take over the job. “She’s like, go ahead, take it. Give him a double!”While Rogan has repeatedly expressed skepticism around the COVID-19 vaccine and has not said whether or not he has received the shot himself, he confirmed that he took ivermectin—an anti-parasitic medication most commonly used for horse deworming—when he tested positive last month."
)), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
))
```

Comment: Can you provide sample of `full_data` using `dput(head(full_data))`?

Comment: Thanks for the comment, @NadPat I added the results from dput(head(full_data)) at the end of my question.

Comment: There was error when copied and pasted `dput()` data. Have you copied the `dput` data correctly? Instead of mediafire can you share google drive link?